# Kendo grid template is not properly showing Bootstrap Toggle, only shows checkbox in column

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Bootstrap Toggle plugin, and trying to get it to show up properly in a kendo grid by using a template and all it shows is the checkbox and not how the switch should look, I know that the plugin is working properly because if I use a plain old table it appears.

Here is how it looks using a plain old table

[image: Html table]

See the toggle switch in the Options column? thats what I am trying to get into the kendo grid options column but as you can see below is how it looks using the kendo grid

[image: Kendo Grid]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#grid').kendoGrid({
    height: 500,
    dataSource: colData,
    columns: [{
        field: "field",
        title: "Columns"
      },
      {
        field: "Options",
        title: "Options",
        template: hereItIs
      }
    ]
  });
});

function hereItIs() {
  var input = '<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" />';
  return input;
}
var colData = [{
    "field": "Apple"
  },
  {
    "field": "Orange"
  },
  {
    "field": "Pear"
  },
  {
    "field": "Plum"
  },
  {
    "field": "Grape"
  },
  {
    "field": "Banana"
  },
  {
    "field": "Watermelon"
  }
];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>


<div id="grid"></div>
```

Any idea's on why the toggle switch is not showing up properly in the kendo grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add an initializer to get it to work:

```
$(function() {
  $('.bootToggle').bootstrapToggle();
})
```

And I had to add a class to know where it should do the initializing..

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="bootToggle" />
```

Made a pen to view the [result](https://codepen.io/Jorgen_Moen/pen/MzpmaW) (my first pen so I hope it works)
(in the pen I changed to templateId instead of template, but that's only because I normally only do mvc telerik-ui and are used to templateId)...